# FileStreamInput read() works just once

Tags: android, arduino, fileinputstream

I have a FileInputStream that reads data from arduino. On my java code reading function in an infinite while loop. read function works just once in the beginning and stop doing its work and jumps to catch block continuously.

Why does it do that ONCE? It should read data continuously. Any suggestions?

```
while(true)
        {
        try 
        {   byte[] inputmessage =new byte[1];
            ret=mInputStream.read(inputmessage);
            SystemClock.sleep(5000);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            SystemClock.sleep(2000);
        }
        finally{

                try {

                    if(mInputStream!=null){         
                        mInputStream.close();
                        }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
veri = Arrays.toString(inputmessage);
        veri = veri.replace("[","");
        veri = veri.replace("]","");
        publishProgress(Integer.parseInt(veri));

         SystemClock.sleep(2000); 
        }


    }
```

Comment: You have two catch blocks so your explanation is not to the point. You are closing the inputstream after the first read so trying to read the second time will cause for an exception.

Comment: so where I close inputstream? I don't get it.

Comment: That i dont get! Don't you see `mInputStream.close();`?

Comment: I asked the wrong question. sorry for the bad English :( where should i close it?

Comment: Aha i understand. You should close it outside the loop. So when the loop is done.

Comment: I'm using INFINITE LOOP :)

Comment: Indeed. Well then do not close at all. Why do you want to close?

Comment: If I don't close it, stream doesn't refresh. So it goes to the same point.

Comment: I don't inderstand. Why should a stream refresh? What is that? You just read the next byte from the stream. If there is no byte available the read will time out and ret is null or negative. You will never read the same byte. What do you mean with the same point?

Comment: arduino is sending different data continously and I have to check what it is. I need data in InputStream and use it. Can i explain myself clearly?

Comment: You are not checking the return value of read(). You are doing nothing with 'ret'. That is a big coding error.

Comment: I understand of course that you have to read continuously. But you don't understand that your code is wrong.

Comment: ret isn't supposed to use because it's the number of bytes returns from read function. I'm using "veri" for my operations.

Comment: Yes i see but if the number of bytes is negative or null you have a problem. You are not checking that.

Comment: **This is horrible code** full of unwise delays and ugly data manipulation and thread messaging.  Start by explaining what you are trying to do.  How is the Arduino connected to the Android?  What sort of message is it sending?

Comment: i know it is horrible code. but its my testing code. I use a device called "UDOO". I used unwise delays because I cant debug ( I dont know how to debug with this device.). It is connected as USB accessory. Arduino part of the device sends a byte of data. (I use digitalRead function to read the pin's state. Then, I wrote the data i read by using ADKwrite function with 10 ms delay on every range of arduino.) The thing I'm trying to do is to doing operations with these datas coming from arduino. Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

An inputstream will go through data only once, you can check with "markSupported()" if you can set a mark in your stream, if you can, you can set it and use "reset" when you want to restart from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @greenapps he can use "rewind()" if mark is supported

Comment: Of course reset is not supported, as it is a stream of data coming from an external device.  But that's beside the point, as reset would not in any way be a solution to the problem experienced.